# How to recursively trigger an intent in DialogFlow from followup yes of that intent itself?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I'm currently working on a dialogflow chat bot and I'm in a situation where I need to recursively trigger an intent.
The scenario is like this:

I created a bot for creating flight request from the conversation of user. For a multicity flight request, I need to add multiple flight sectors. After adding each sectors, the user will be prompted whether to add another sector or not. If user says yes, then the bot need to trigger the multicity flight request intent again. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You have tagged this with both the `dialogflow-es` and `dialogflow-cx` tags. These are very different products, and have very different solutions to your question. Can you clarify which you're using? The more examples showing what you've tried, and what hasn't worked, the better our chances are of being able to help you.

Comment: @Prisoner Thanks for your comment. I'm using dialogflow-es. Currently I don't know any solutions for this or whether this is correct approach or not. My requirement is that I want to recursively collect data from user using the intents. For that, is there any way to trigger an intent recursively?

Answer (score 0):

Intents are "triggered" by a user phrase or event. Trying to trigger them "recursively" probably isn't exactly what you want. Remember - Intents represent *what the user says* and *not* how you handle or reply to what they say.

What it sounds like you're trying to do is:

- Once a user has given a response, prompt them if they would like to add another sector.
- If they reply yes, prompt them for that information. (If they reply no, go handle that.)
- Keep repeating this until they reply no.

Keep in mind that this loop is driven by *what the user says*.

Based on this, the best approach is:

- The Intent that handles the user giving information should have an Input Context, so it will only be triggered when that Context has a lifespan greater than 0.
- When the user responds that they have more information, set that Context to a lifespan greater than 0 with your webhook and prompt them to give you the information.
- If the user responds they are done, set the Context lifespan to 0 so the Intent won't be triggered.